# finally block in angular 2 promise

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-promise

I observe that In angular 2 there is no finally block for promise API

angular 1 :

```
 loadUsers() {
  fetch('/api/users').then((response) => {
    return response.json();
  }).then((data) => {
    this.users = data;
  }).catch((ex) => {
    console.error('Error fetching users', ex);
  }).finally(() => {
     this.userLoaded = true;
};
```

**Assuming I have to do same thing in angular 2**

How to add finally block in angular 2 promise , as of now there are only `then & catch blocks` available in angular 2. If not finally then is there any way to add cleanup code after execution of each method , where do i write code to do finally block activities  ?

Comment: Have you looked into using observables instead of promises?

Comment: In the future: `angularjs` is for AngularJS 1.x questions.

Comment: @jonrsharpe This may be an opinionated statement, but I feel observables do not solve the same problem domain as promises.

Comment: @Katana314 on what basis? They're both abstractions around async behaviour.

Answer (score 15):

The easiest way to do this is to use the [promise.finally shim](https://github.com/es-shims/Promise.prototype.finally).

- Add it with `npm install --save promise.prototype.finally`
- Add the typings: `npm install --save-dev @types/promise.prototype.finally`
- In your main class, before bootstrapping the application, add the following code:

```
import { shim } from 'promise.prototype.finally';
shim();
```

You should now be able to use `finally` on your promises.

Comment: I am getting an error with typescript 2.1.5 saying all declaration of promise must have identical declaration.

Comment: @ShyamalParikh thankfully the DefinitelyTyped repo has been updated with the correct typings. I've updated my answer above to reflect this.

Comment: @fiznool, Thanks for that.  One thing to add, (I'm using Angular4) I think it's best to place the shim in the polyfills.ts file.  I placed the following at the bottom of that file `/***************************************************************************************************
 * PROMISES .finally SHIM
 */`

`import { shim as finallyShim } from 'promise.prototype.finally';
finallyShim();`

Answer (score 1):

This is usually done using Promise.always. This takes one function, and adds a new `.then` on the promise that gives the same function for both success and fail states. If the function is not available in the given promise-based environment, it's pretty easy to polyfill in.

```
Promise.always = function(p, fn) {
  return p.then(fn, fn);
}
```

usage:

```
var prom = fetch('/api/users').then...
Promise.always(prom, () => {
  this.userLoaded = true;
});
return prom;
```

Comment: You should **not** modify the `Promise` object. https://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/03/02/maintainable-javascript-dont-modify-objects-you-down-own/

Answer (score 1):

## Modern solution in 2019-2020

First of all, you should avoid manually adding polyfills without a good reason for it, don't do it blindly because you've read it somewhere.

The problem you encounter has two sides: typing declarations and the implementation.

In order to use `Promise.finally` in your code without typing errors you should add `es2018.promise` to the `lib` option in your `tsconfig.json` file.

For modern projects you should use the following configuration (which is default in Angular 8):

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    …
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

This will fix the typing errors you have in the editor.

Also, according to the docs and my observations the correct polyfill for `Promise.finally` will be added by the Angular compiler automatically, you don't have to install or add anything.

But, in general, you could add a polyfill (only if it is proven to be required) in `./src/polyfills.ts` file using `core-js` library. Always try to use `core-js` instead of other libraries, cause it's an industry standard and it's used by Angular internally.

For example, `Promise.finally` polyfill could be added like this:

`import 'core-js/features/promise/finally';`

---

See more at [core-js documentation](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js).

Also, make sure to read [browser-support](https://angular.io/guide/browser-support#browser-support) and [differential-loading](https://angular.io/guide/deployment#differential-loading) articles of Angular documentation.